# Typescript Generic Union

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

So I have Array of generic object and want to iterate over the but typescript wont allow me. Here is some sample code. Any Suggestions of how this can be solved.

```
type someGeneric<T> = { item: T };

type stringGeneric = someGeneric<string>;

type numberGeneric = someGeneric<number>;

type someFunction = <T>(generic: someGeneric<T>) => T;

const someFunction: someFunction = (generic) => generic.item;

const stringGeneric: stringGeneric = { item: 'some String' },
    numberGeneric: numberGeneric = { item: 12 };

let genericArray = [stringGeneric, numberGeneric];
genericArray.forEach(generic => {
    someFunction(generic); // Error On This line.
});
```

You can just copy-paste the code to [this link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play). I cant seem to share the code.

Comment: “*Error On This line*” What is the error?

Comment: @MTCoster The error (the important part anyway) is `Argument of type 'someGeneric<string> | someGeneric<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'someGeneric<string>'.`

Comment: Off topic, but may I suggest always using TitleCase for type names. e.g. SomeGeneric<T>. This matches the TS community and TS team's code.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the function accepts a parameter of type `someGeneric<T>` if we try to pass in a parameter of type `someGeneric<number> | someGeneric<string>` typescript will not try to infer `T` from this it will just say the union is not compatible with the type `someGeneric<T>`

We can change the definition of the function so that the type parameter extends `someGeneric<any>`. This constraint will be compatible with the union. We can then use a conditional type to extract the item type from the `T` using a conditional type. Since conditional types distribute over unions the result of the extraction will be a union of the generic parameters to `someGeneric<T>`

```
type someGeneric<T> = { item: T };

type stringGeneric = someGeneric<string>;

type numberGeneric = someGeneric<number>;

type extractItemFromSomeGeneric<T extends someGeneric<any>> = T extends someGeneric<infer U> ? U : never;  
type someFunction = <T extends someGeneric<any>>(generic: T) => extractItemFromSomeGeneric<T>;

const someFunction: someFunction = (generic) => generic.item;

const stringGeneric: stringGeneric = { item: 'some String' },
    numberGeneric: numberGeneric = { item: 12 };

let someGeneric = [stringGeneric, numberGeneric];
someGeneric.forEach(generic => {
    someFunction(generic); // retruns string | number
});
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20someGeneric%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20item%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20stringGeneric%20%3D%20someGeneric%3Cstring%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20numberGeneric%20%3D%20someGeneric%3Cnumber%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20extractItemFromSomeGeneric%3CT%20extends%20someGeneric%3Cany%3E%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20someGeneric%3Cinfer%20U%3E%20%3F%20U%20%3A%20never%3B%20%20%0D%0Atype%20someFunction%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20someGeneric%3Cany%3E%3E(generic%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20extractItemFromSomeGeneric%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20someFunction%3A%20someFunction%20%3D%20(generic)%20%3D%3E%20generic.item%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20stringGeneric%3A%20stringGeneric%20%3D%20%7B%20item%3A%20'some%20String'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20numberGeneric%3A%20numberGeneric%20%3D%20%7B%20item%3A%2012%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20someGeneric%20%3D%20%5BstringGeneric%2C%20numberGeneric%5D%3B%0D%0AsomeGeneric.forEach(generic%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20someFunction(generic)%3B%20%2F%2F%20retruns%20string%20%7C%20number%0D%0A%7D)%3B)